# How do I import an entire OpenCV build into Visual Studio 2013 to test it

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, build, import

I have a OpenCv build I would like to test without installing it in Windows 8.1. How do I import [this](https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv) entire OpenCV build into Visual Studio 2013,  including this module [here](https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv_contrib) to test it. I could use exact instructions on how to do this.   My VisualStudio is in good working order and I can compile OpenCv on it.  I'm  using the 2.4.9 build [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/) now.  I don't want the 2.4.9 build of OpenCV to get in the way of a pure test of the build I referenced at the top of the page though..Thanks in advance for any help:)

Comment: are you using git to manage the src code ? (or are you moving around zips?)

Comment: @berak I'm going to download  this build https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv so I can import it and also this module https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv_contrib and I would like instructions on how to do this,  if you can help me  I would be very grateful